# PNG Image not displaying for desktop icon on Fedora 16/17 with Gnome

Tags: fedora, gnome, desktop, icons

I attempted to create a desktop icon in Fedora Gnome but I only get a generic binary icon for my application. Installing Gimp or OpenOffice magically makes my icon appear.

I used Google Chrome on Fedora as an reference for making a desktop icon using png images. Google Chrome uses 32-bit PNG files in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/#x#/apps/google-chrome.png`, where `#x#` is the various resolutions: 16x16, 22x22, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64, 128x128, and 256x256. The permissions on these files were all `0644` or `-rw-r--r--`. Google places their `google-chrome.desktop` file in `/usr/local/share/applications/` with permission `0644`.

**Attempt:**

I copied all of these conditions except the location of the .desktop file:

- `my-app.desktop` file was placed in `/usr/share/applications` with permission `0644`
- All png files were saved as 32-bit images and properly located in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/#x#/apps` with permission `0644`
- My desktop file is as follows:

(my-app.desktop)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=My-App
GenericName=My Application
Comment=Test Application
Terminal=false
Icon=my-app.png
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/my-app/my-app
MimeType=application/x-executable
Categories=Network
```

**Result:**

Navigating to `/usr/share/applications` my my-app.desktop file looks like a plain file:
[image]

In the Gnome desktop menu, my application looks like a generic binary file:
[image]

Installing Gimp or OpenOffice will make my icon appear as intended without modification to the `my-app.desktop` file or the png files.

I have tried the following different things to solve the problem:

- Changing `Icon=my-app.png` to `Icon=my-app` in my-app.desktop
- Saving the PNG files as 24-bit

Comment: Can you upload the problematic PNG file somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what does `~/.xsession-errors` say? Does it hint on the error that a validation would give?

What does `desktop-file-validate` say?

It should say something like this:

```
sm.desktop: error: (will be fatal in the future): value "sm.png" for key "Icon" in group "Desktop Entry" is an icon name with an extension, but there should be no extension as described in the Icon Theme Specification if the value is not an absolute path
```

**Edit:**
Here's what the desktop file looks like fixed:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=My-App
GenericName=My Application
Comment=Test Application
Terminal=false
Icon=my-app
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/my-app/my-app
MimeType=application/x-executable;
Categories=Network;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I wasn't able to discern if any of the information in `~/.xsession-errors` was related to my problem. However running `desktop-file-validation` showed the error you mentioned plus 2 more errors.

As mentioned in my question, I already tried removing the extention and still got the same problem. However I'll try rectifying the other two errors and let you know if that works. The other two errors were caused by a missing semicolon `;` at the end of `MimeType` and `Categories`.

Comment: Just verified it to be working. Removing the image extension and adding a semicolon at the end of `MimeType` and `Categories` did the trick. I've modified your answer to include the fixed desktop file. Thanks!

Comment: My images were **jpg**, I had to convert them to **png** and remove the filename extension (no absolute path was given). But two of the apps I’ve created still don’t show their icon.

Comment: Remove the "Terminal=false" line. This appears to be a Unity/GNOME bug.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the "Terminal=false" line. That seems to trigger a bug in GNOME and Unity's handling of the .desktop file. KDE is not affected by this bug.

I had a similar problem and after removing that line my icons are showing up properly.

This affects even recent desktops, at least Ubuntu 17.04 and Fedora Core 26 are still suffering from this bug.