# Consistent Icons for Zoom in Gnome Wayland on NixOS

Tags: gnome, wayland, gnome-shell, nixos, zoom

I use zoom on Gnome Wayland in [NixOS](https://nixos.org) ([dotfiles](https://github.com/joshrule/config)). The problem I’m trying to solve is that while I can see the zoom icon in the launcher/overview:

[image: screenshot of Zoom icon in Gnome overlay]

I get the default application icon everywhere else:

[image: default application icon used for Zoom in Gnome taskbar]

I had a similar problem with [foot](https://codeberg.org/dnkl/foot), because the desktop entry was missing the line `StartupWMClass = foot`. I wrote a [custom desktop entry](https://github.com/joshrule/config/blob/ba01eb5dff7f9274ceffae2638efea4ed7577723/users/rule/home.nix#L150-L166), and that resolved the problem.

Now, the default `Zoom.desktop file` already contains StartupWMClass = zoom:

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Zoom
Comment=Zoom Video Conference
Exec=/nix/store/v651rqca7bjrbvgc1760qcskj7lcgapn-zoom-5.15.2.4260/bin/zoom %U
Icon=Zoom
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Network;Application;
StartupWMClass=zoom
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/zoommtg;x-scheme-handler/zoomus;x-scheme-handler/tel;x-scheme-handler/callto;x-scheme-handler/zoomphonecall;application/x-zoom
X-KDE-Protocols=zoommtg;zoomus;tel;callto;zoomphonecall;
Name[en_US]=Zoom
```

I've tried changing the capitalization (i.e. `StartupWMClass=Zoom`), but that doesn't solve the problem.

Also, running `desktop-file-validate` on `Zoom.desktop` (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41135/png-image-not-displaying-for-desktop-icon-on-fedora-16-17-with-gnome)) warns of a couple deprecations, but gives no errors. Similarly, I see no errors in `~/.xsession-errors`.

In addition, looking glass (i.e. Alt + F2 “lg”) doesn’t report a known `wmclass` nor that Gnome used `Zoom.desktop` to launch zoom.

[image: Gnome Looking Glass reports no wmclass or desktop entry for zoom.]

What is going on here, and how can I consistently use the zoom icon throughout Gnome?

Comment: Have you tried restarting GNOME entirely? I have consistent Zoom icons in the places you mention.

Comment: @l0b0 - Good idea, but it doesn't seem to be the problem here. I have logged out and back in and rebooted several times. I have also reapplied my system configuration (i.e. `sudo nixos-rebuild switch --flake .#`) several times, but the issue remains.